# Mars Mips Assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

Hello everyone im very new to mips assembly and my teacher gave us the following solution. The program basically finds the min and max vals in a array using the stack. I get completely lost especially using the stack since I cant visualize any of this. Please maybe explain the different lines in human language, I would greatly appreciate it!

```
.data
array:   .word  4, 10, -1, 8, 0, 22, 100, 100, -5, 45
.text
main:
la   $a0, array
li   $a1, 10
jal  minmax
j    exit
minmax:
addi $sp, $sp, -8
sw   $a0, 0($sp)
sw   $a1, 4($sp)
lw   $v0, 0($a0)
lw   $v1, 0($a0)
addi $a1, $a1, -1
next:
    ble  $a1, $zero, return
addi $a0, $a0, 4
addi $a1, $a1, -1
lw   $t0, 0($a0)
blt  $v0, $t0, max
move $v0, $t0
max:   
  bgt  $v1, $t0, next
move $v1, $t0
j    next
return:  
lw   $a0, 0($sp)
lw   $a1, 4($sp)
addi $sp, $sp, 8
jr   $ra
exit:
```

Comment: I didn't remove the C++ tag, but you may want to as it does not seem relevant to your question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  However, questions like "rewrite this code in another language for me" are not within the scope of what this site is for.  Please see the help center: ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)  There is an Edit button, and what you could do to make this an acceptable question would be to give your own explanation line by line and point to the *specific* part you don't understand.  If your understanding is blocked very early in reading it, then you should ask a much shorter question *just about that part*.

Comment: *"I get completely lost especially using the stack since I cant visualize any of this."* stack is ordinary computer memory, similar to `.data` area (and after all, to `.text` area too, in Von Neumann architecture the memory used for instructions is same as memory used for data, the distinction is only logical on operator level, the HW can't recognize which is which). The only special thing about "stack" is, that some CPUs have instructions implicitly supporting "sp" register like x86 `call + ret` instructions. Not so on MIPS, where `sp` is minimally different from other regs.

Comment: (IIRC, it's enforced by CPU to have bottom bit cleared to contain even address, but I may recall it wrongly) ... so you can run the code in the debugger, and observe the memory view pointing to the addresses around `$sp` to "visualize" it better, how the machine operates. But most of the "stack" magic is convention and logic, how the memory is used by the code, very little is hard-wired in the CPU, i.e. you can easily write code which will use the "stack" in non common way (potentially breaking when intermixed with code which expects "common" usage).